# Create a custom URL and outputting HTML form data

Tags: python, forms, python-3.x, flask

For my first Flask project I wanted to create a basic Flask app using Riot Game's API for League of Legends. I've got all the processing of API working but I'm having trouble going about outputting it.

I take the input from a form on one page.

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="{{ url_for('current_game_output') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Summoner Name" name="summoner_name">
        <select class="form-control" name="region">
            <option value="oce">Oceanic</option>
            <option value="na">North America</option>
            <option value="euw">Europe West</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Send">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And I am trying to output the data returned from the API onto the next page.

```
{% extends "header.html" %}
{% block body %}

    <h3> Team 2 </h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <th width="48%">Summoner Name</th>
            <th width="48%">Champion</th>
            <th width="4%">Pic</th>
        </tr>
        {% for player in team1 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ player[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ player[1] }}</td>
                <td><img width="20px" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/championIcons/') }}{{ player[1].replace(" ", "") }}_Square_0.png"></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>

    <h3> Team 1 </h3>
    <table class="table table-bordered" width="50%">
        <tr>
            <th width="48%">Summoner Name</th>
            <th width="48%">Champion</th>
            <th width="4%">Pic</th>
        </tr>
        {% for player in team2 %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ player[0] }}</td>
                <td>{{ player[1] }}</td>
                <td><img width="20px" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/championIcons/') }}{{ player[1].replace(" ", "") }}_Square_0.png"></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

I'd like the URL of the output page to be dynamic'/currentgame/region/username' but keep getting errors when trying to do so.

Relevant part of my views.py file (hidden my api key):

```
@app.route('/header')
def header():
    return render_template("header.html")

@app.route('/current')
def current():
    return render_template("current.html")


@app.route('/currentgame/<region>/<name>', methods=['POST'])
def current_game_output(region, name):
    region = request.form['region']
    summoner_name = request.form['summoner_name']
    api = RiotAPI('APIKEYGOESHERE', region)
    team1, team2 = current_game_data(summoner_name, region, api)
    return render_template("output.html",team1=team1,team2=team2)
```

Any help/pointers on the best way to output/return the data would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should post the error as well.

In a quick looks this should be fixed:

```
@app.route('/currentgame/<string:region>/<string:name>', methods=['POST'])
def current_game_output(region, name):
    region = request.form['region']
    summoner_name = request.form['summoner_name']
    api = RiotAPI('APIKEYGOESHERE', region)
    team1, team2 = current_game_data(summoner_name, region, api)
    return render_template("output.html",team1=team1,team2=team2)
```

Change route to `/currentgame/<string:region>/<string:name>`

Comment: OK Thanks. I tried the fix you suggeted and recieved "Internal Server Error". I looked in the logs and it had these errors: http://pastebin.com/1d1zGP9W

Comment: @AConway Update the answer. Take a look now.

Comment: Thanks, that solved that error. Unfortunately I'm receiving this error now http://pastebin.com/hei1S4B0 . Is there somewhere I'm meant to be setting the variables for the URL? Thanks

Comment: This error is because you arent specifying `region` and `name` parameter in your form's `url_for`. `url_for('current_game_output' , region = some_val , name = some_other_val )`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that error but now I'm receiving a 404 not found error.

Comment: Got a github link?